# Can two users both control a third machine simultaneously using Synergy?

Tags: macos, network-shares, synergy

I've been a Synergy user for some time now, as I use a PC on the left side of my Mac.

My girlfriend and I both have our desks on each side of the other, and we'd like to know if it were possible for the both of us to control the PC in the middle, with our own separate mouse & keyboards. Here's a crude drawing of our setup

(1) her pc     (2) my pc     (3) my mac

Currently, 3 is running a synergy server, and 2 is running the client. But like I said, I'm wondering if there's a way for 1 & 3 to both control 2 with their own mouse and keyboard.

I'd ~love~ to have it set up where we could go even farther, and have both of our mice & keyboards able to control all 3 computers at the same time, for moments when we need to click or press keys for each other. But that seems a little too much to ask!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure with Mac, but with Windows PC you can run multiple instances of synergy. I've done what you're talking about successfully, and it works pretty well, at least the two computers controlling one, if three computers all control each other (which you could setup in the older version) then you get stuck in a loop...